# Textfield Validation for no numbers or special characters

Tags: validation, javafx, textfield

I would like to have a validation for my textfield where it does not accept special characters or numbers

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(fnamefield.getText().matches("[0-9]") || fnamefield.getText().isEmpty()) {
                ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Error!", "Please enter your full name.\n"
                        + "Please make sure no");
                return;
            }
```

Here I am trying to only include the no numbers validation to start with however I'm unsure how to continue.

Comment: should be `.matches(".*[0-9].*")`. Furthermore what are "special characters"? Are umlauts allowed? What about acents/circumflex ect.?

Comment: I was thinking something like: [!@#$%^&*(),.?":{}|<>]

Answer (score 0):

I think that one valid solution for you is that you check all your conditions at the same time. In this case you are checking if it is not an empty string and if it contains only letters and blanks. A valid regex for that will be `[aA-zZ ]+$`. Notice that this regex accepts a `String` that contains only blanks, what may be harmful for your application, but your method also does.

An example on how to use the regex to match the strings you want is shown:

```
public class MyClass {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        System.out.println("Are these valid strings?");
        System.out.println("Not valid 1".matches("[aA-zZ ']+$")); //false
        System.out.println("Not valid!".matches("[aA-zZ ']+$")); //false
        System.out.println("".matches("[aA-zZ ']+$")); //false Also invalid
        System.out.println(" ".matches("[aA-zZ ']+$")); //true VALID!!
        System.out.println("For sure I'm valid".matches("[aA-zZ ']+$")); //true
    }
}
```

**In the example of code I have added the `'` to the regex to match "I'm" but you can remove it if you don't want it.**

Finally, your piece of code would look like:

```
public void handle(ActionEvent event) {
            if(!fnamefield.getText().matches("[aA-zZ ]+$")) {
                ErrorAlert(Alert.AlertType.ERROR, gridPane.getScene().getWindow(), "Error!", "Please enter your full name.\n"
                        + "Please make sure no");
                return;
            }
```